# Finding Jump Probability For Time Series Data

Tags: stochastic-processes, implied-volatility, python, stochastic-volatility

I'm relatively new here, so if it seems like I'm asking a bad question, go easy on me.

So I was looking at the [Merton Jump Diffusion Stochastic Model](http://stuartreid.co.za/interactive-stochastic-processes/) on Turing Finance's article. Instead of creating something that generates jumps given a jump probability, I wanted to figure out the jump probability of any given time series I'm given. Such a variable will be heavily dependent on a few things:

1. That I can detect jumps while doing feed-forward testing.
2. That I have a memory of all the jumps for a given time-series data set and I have the distance between each jump as a result.
3. That I also have some sense of what the jump volatility would be.

It's important for a model I'm generating.

Pythonically, you could say I want to run the following steps inside of the backtest:

```
def get_jump_prob_vol(series):
    moving_vol1, moving_vol2 = get_rolling_volatility_two(series) # returns a rolling STD of the the time series
    jprob, jvol = get_jump_information(moving_vol1, moving_vol2)
    return jprob, jvol
```

Here's what I have so far.

I have the thought that jumps would be detectable using diverge between two rolling volatility measures (standard deviations). One would be short, and would better capture quick swings, while the other would be longer in time horizon, and would allow for the algo to capture larger volatility measures. Times when the short volatility approaches a local max, and the std divergence is over a threshold, would indicate when a jump has happened, and could possibly show how steep (strong) the jump was. A gaussian distribution that's a cumulation of all of the jumps this would have recorded would be my `jump vol` and `jump prob`.

I haven't had the chance to try this out yet. I wondered if others have done anything similar in the past. Knowing so would let me figure out if I'm heading in the right direction.

Comment: Small request -- when you have Python or other code, it's quite helpful to include the import statements. That way we can tell what library you're using.

Comment: It's a pseudo-code example. I'd probably use ta-lib and numpy.